# Struts 2 Validation not working with dynamic form fields

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, visitor-pattern

I am working on an application where a user can enter multiple addresses. I am using Struts2 XML validation and for those fields [Address (Country, City, Street)], I have used visitor validator but it is not working.
The validation is working fine on remaining fields.

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem ?

**EmployeeForm.jsp**

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Employee</title>

<script language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var counts=rowCount-1;
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var street = document.createElement("input");
        street.type = "text";
        street.name="employeeModel.addresses["+counts+"].street";
        cell1.appendChild(houseNum);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var city = document.createElement("input");
        city.type = "text";
        city.name="employeeModel.addresses["+counts+"].city";
        cell2.appendChild(city);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var country = document.createElement("input");
        country.type = "text";
        country.name="employeeModel.addresses["+counts+"].country";
        cell3.appendChild(country);

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<s:form action="addEmployee.action" method="post" >
    <s:textfield label="Name" name="employeeModel.employeeName" size="20" />

    <table id="addressesTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Street</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>Country</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="employeeModel.addresses[0].street" /></td>    
        <td><input type="text" name="employeeModel.addresses[0].city" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="employeeModel.addresses[0].country" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Add More" onclick="addRow('addressesTable')" />
    <s:submit />

</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EmployeeAction-Validation.xml**

```xml
<validators>
<field name="employeeModel.employeeName">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>Name is required.</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
<field name="employeeModel.addresses" >
      <field-validator type="visitor">
          <message></message>
      </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

**EmployeeModel-Validation.xml**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
  <field name="employeeModel.addresses" >
      <field-validator type="visitor">
          <message></message>
      </field-validator>
  </field>
</validators>
```

**EmployeeAction.java**

```
 package com.action;

import com.model.EmployeeModel;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private EmployeeModel employeeModel;

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public EmployeeModel getEmployeeModel() {
        return employeeModel;
    }

    public void setEmployeeModel(EmployeeModel employeeModel) {
        this.employeeModel = employeeModel;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeModel.java**

```
 package com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeModel implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -484846216250373240L;
    private String employeeName;
    private List<AddressModel> addresses;

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public List<AddressModel> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }
    public void setAddresses(List<AddressModel> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
}
```

**AddressModel.java**

```
 package com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class AddressModel implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6965346469594926268L;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }   
}
```

**struts.xml**

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="addEmployee" class="com.action.EmployeeAction" >
            <result name="success">/Result.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/EmployeeForm.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a validation file for the Visitor Validator ? "Visitor" means *"for this specific field, you will find the validation rules in another XML file, located in the model file folder, not in the action folder"*.

Comment: I got the error. Please update your question by adding the visitor validator file name, package and code, and the AddressModel code too, so I can answer in a more complete way

Comment: Sir I have edited. Please check. 
The EmployeeModel-Validation.xml is kept with the model class and the EmployeeAction-Validation.xml is kept with the Action class in separate package.
I also followed your blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **one** `EmployeeModel` object, that has **multiple** `AddressModel` objects.

This means that in the Action validation file, you need to use **simple** validation for `EmployeeModel` properties, and **visitor** validation for `AddressModel` object.

You are correctly saying that `AddressModel` must be validated through visitor validation here:

```xml
<field name="employeeModel.addresses" >
    <field-validator type="visitor">
```

but then, instead of the validation file for `AddressModel`, you are trying to use a validation file for `EmployeeModel` !

Instead of

**EmployeeModel-Validation.xml**

you need to use

**AddressModel-Validation.xml**

and inside it, you need to validate the simple properties, without any `employeeModel` in front of them (because this validation could be visitor-used by many different validation files, with different actions and models containing `AddressModel`, that doesn't care about its parent objects):

```xml
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="country">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>Country is required.</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

#### EDIT:

You've also forgot to name the attributes of your `AddressModel` object; add them:

```xml
<td><input type="text" name="employeeModel.addresses[0].street" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="employeeModel.addresses[0].city"    /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="employeeModel.addresses[0].country"  /></td>
```

and do the same in your javascript code.

Comment: Sir I have updated the field names, still no success :(
What could be the problem now ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's modelDriven... that you are not even using in your page :) **Just remove it**, it causes only troubles and adds unnecessary complexity. Also change the definition and the setter of addresses from ArrayList to the interface List

Comment: Did both things.. But same result.
Is that due to the fields are html fields ?

Comment: No, HTML fields are perfectly fine. I see that the capitalzied V in XML validation files is wrong, it should be lowercase (but I don't know if it prevents the validation from working). That said, do you have constructors with parameters in your VOs that you've not posted here ? If yes, add a no-args constructor too. Then post here your struts.xml configuration (interceptor stack and action config)

Comment: There must be something *very* strange going on :| if you confirm that the file `AddressModel-validation.xml` is in the `com.model` package. Note that **you must implement Serializable on all your VOs** (EmployeeModel and AddressModel), but if this'll be the culprit, I'd be surprised. Do this last update, if it doesn't work, take your modified code and dump it here over the original (except the XML validation files that are the subject of the Q&A, and should be added to your question, to not replace the original ones).

Comment: Sir I checked it again. The validation is working fine. Just the error messages are not being displayed on the HTML fields.

Comment: They are not displayed because you are using html tags and not struts tags (and only the first row is available on page load). Put an <s:fielderror /> tag on top of your form and they'll be drawn.